# How to write greek letters in an xml file, using Python

Tags: python, xml, unicode

I want to create an xml file that will contain greek words. I tried to use .encode('utf-8'), but in that way greek words are converted to "\xce\xa4\xce..." in my xml. I want the greek format to remain.
The greek words in the following example is 'ΤΟ ΣΤΟΙΧΗΜΑ'.
Is there a way to do this?

```
from dicttoxml import dicttoxml
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

greek_words = 'ΤΟ ΣΤΟΙΧΗΜΑ'

mydict1 = {'title':greek_words, 'date':'19/05/2017'}
mydict2 = {'title':'GOAL', 'date':'25/05/90'}
mylist = []
mylist.append(mydict1)
mylist.append(mydict2)

xml = dicttoxml(mylist, custom_root='newspapers', attr_type=False)
dom = parseString(xml)
print(dom.toprettyxml())

with open("newspapers.xml", "w") as f:
    f.write(dom.toprettyxml())
```

Running this script, the following error occurs:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 56-57: character maps to undefined

Comment: Try `greek_words = u'ΤΟ ΣΤΟΙΧΗΜΑ'` or `greek_words = b'ΤΟ ΣΤΟΙΧΗΜΑ'` (will break stuff, you'll need to open `wb` instead of `w` and make sure that dom handles byets data). Or you could do `greek_words.encode('UTF-8')` or `base64.b64encode(greek_words)`.

Comment: try to change `open("newspapers.xml", "w")` to `open("newspapers.xml", "w", encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: Thank you both! Oleksandr your solution worked!